# Why black screen after Ubuntu installed?

Tags: system-installation

I have just installed Ubuntu using `ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso`. I had Endless OS on my lepton and I decided to overwrite it by Ubuntu.

Now, when I start my laptop, I first see "acer" logo, then, for a second I see a purple screen and then black screen.

What can I do to bring my new laptop back to the operational state?

Answer (score 1):

There is a open bug that causes random hard CPU lockups (caused by intel-microcode), some during the boot process (which makes it difficult to troubleshoot). Try starting it with dis_ucode_ldr grub parameter.

More in the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+bug/1759920

Comment: Can I avoid this bug by using other (for example older) version of Ubuntu?

Comment: How can I start with dis_ucode_ldr grub parameter?

Comment: @Roman: you can hold shift during boot time to get into grub menu. Then you can edit start parameters. More about it here: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters